# Why no "extra coefficient K" in the formula of Laplace's law of succession?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Below is an example about the calculation of *Laplace's law of succession*:

Suppose we observe $y$ responses out of $n$ binomial trials. Assuming the trials are indenpendent, with unknown response probabilty $\theta$. The event it will happen next time is $\widetilde{Y}$.

The binomial sampling distribution is:

$p(y|n,\theta)=\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ y\end{array}\right)\theta^{y}(1-\theta)^{n-y}$  (Eq. 1)

Suppose a $Beta(1,1)$ (i.e., uniform) prior on $\theta$, and consider the case $y=n$, that is, the event has happended at every opportunity. The posterior distribution is:

$p(\theta|y,n)\propto p(y|n,\theta)*p(\theta) \propto Beta(y+1,1)$  (Eq. 2)

**NOTE: in Eq. 2, there is "proportion symbol $\propto$", not a "$=$".**

So, I give it a "coefficient": $K$.

$p(\theta|y,n)=K*Beta(y+1,1)$  (Eq. 3)

Then Laplace's law of succession (i.e., posterior-predictive expectation) is:

\begin{split}
E[\widetilde{Y}|y,n]&=p(\widetilde{Y}=1|y,n)\\
&=\int_{}^{} \theta*p(\theta|y,n)d\theta\\
&=\int_{}^{} \theta*K*\frac{\Gamma(y+2)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(1)}*\theta^{y}(1-\theta)^{0}d\theta\\
&=K*\frac{y+1}{y+2}=K*\frac{n+1}{n+2}
\end{split}

But the correct answer should be:$\frac{n+1}{n+2}$.

Why do I have an extra coefficient "$K$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $p(\theta|y,n)$ is actually equal to $\text{Beta}(y+1,1)$, not just proportional. Yes, they're both proportional to the middle term, $p(y|n,\theta)p(\theta)$, however they're equal, which means $K=1$ and your result is correct. The proportionality argument is generally used to describe the format, and therefore type, of the PDF; where you actually found that $p(\theta|y,n)$ is of *Beta* form.

Also, from pure mathematical view, you can easily check that they're equal if you integrate both sides, because since both are PDFs, they *must* integrate to $1$.
$$1=\int_0^1 p(\theta|y,n)d\theta=\int_0^1 K\text{Beta}(y+1,1)d\theta=1$$
which leaves us with $1=K$.

Comment: The mathematical view helps me understand better! $K$ is truly 1